# Is it possible to use superscript in a category title?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, menu, html

I have a couple of items that I want to refer to as trademarked in category titles. I attempted to use:

`For Double J<sup>tm</sup> and Jlite<sup>tm</sup> Headlight Brackets`

But the `<sup>` and `</sup>` show up and do not work as html like I hoped they would.

The question: Is there a way to format superscript in category titles so that they show up as superscript when viewed in the product navigation on the public site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
&trade;
```

That's the html element for the trademark symbol.  In most fonts, it should look like superscript.

For example ™

Comment: Short and sweet and works like a charm. Thanks @tj-gamble-at-jamersan. I don't have enough points to give this an up vote so here it is in the comment. Thanks!

Comment: as_whitley, if this helped, please be sure to select the checkbox to accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry about that @tj-gamble-at-jamersan. I tried to up-vote it but didn't try the check mark. Newbie blues. It is checked now.

Answer (score 0):

The title is printed using the method `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Output::categoryAttribute`.

Notice this section:

```
if ($attribute->getIsHtmlAllowedOnFront() && $attribute->getIsWysiwygEnabled()) {
    if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isUrlDirectivesParsingAllowed()) {
        $attributeHtml = $this->_getTemplateProcessor()->filter($attributeHtml);
    }
}
```

So you are allowed to use html for an attribute if the attribute has `is_html_allowed_on_front` set to true and `is_wysiwyg_enabled` also true.

You can do this by creating an upgrade script like this:

```
$this->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'name', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', true);
$this->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'name', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', true);
```

Or you can change it directly in your db.
Find the id of the `name` attribute like this:

```
SELECT 
    attribute_id
FROM
    eav_attribute
WHERE
    attribute_code = 'name' and 
    entity_type_id = (
                     SELECT 
                         entity_type_id 
                     FROM
                         eav_entity_type
                     WHERE
                         entity_type_code = 'catalog_category'
                     );
```

Then, with the id you get run this:

```
UPDATE `catalog_eav_attribute` SET
    is_html_allowed_on_front = 1,
    is_wysiwyg_enabled = 1
WHERE attribute_id = 'result from above query'
```